# How to Update multiple items at the single time - Directus 9.24.0v

Tags: javascript, axios, hook, patch, directus

I am trying to update multiple items simultaneously from extension hooks, but not happening I am facing 400 lousy request errors and using Axios requests patch requests.

can anyone tell me where I made a mistake here?

```js
await Axios.patch(
        http: //localhost:8080/admin/content/vendor_pos,
        {
            "keys": [1, 2, 3],
            "data": {
                "status": true
            }
        }, 
        {
         headers: {
           Authorization: `Bearer xx,
          Content-Type': 'application/JSON,
        },
    });
```